# I've lost my key, but I found it just now

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

Are the two sentences correct?

> I've lost my key, but luckily I've found it again.
>
> I've lost my key, but luckily I found it just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is correct.

"I've lost" (I have lost) is the *present perfect tense*. It is not logically possible for you to simultaneously have lost *and* found your key, which makes the first example incorrect. Neither it is possible to lose your key in the present and then find it in the past, making the second example wrong.

"Have lost" is a little different from, for example, "have opened". You could say "I have opened and closed the door", which would mean you carried out the two actions of opening, and then closing the door. "I have lost" can only mean that something is presently lost, because losing something is *accidental* and you cannot pinpoint exactly when you lost something - if you could, then you could go right to it and it wouldn't be lost anymore!

So, the only logical possibility is that both the losing and the finding are in the past, which you could express in different ways, for example:

> I lost my key, but luckily I found it again.

or

> I **had** lost my key, but luckily I found it again.

You could shorten this statement a lot - the important thing to remember is that "I *have* lost" means it is lost *now*, which it cannot be if you have already found it. So you might say:

> I lost, and then found my key.

Or simply:

> I found my lost key!

Comment: Could it be expedient to use The present perfect if one is holding the lost and found key in his hand saying: "I lost my key, but luckily I have just recovered it and here it is!"?

Comment: I **thought** I('d) lost my key but luckily I'**ve just found** it

Comment: Can't you say "I've lost and found my key"?

Comment: @StephenLiu What do you think - can you say "I have no keys and one key"?

Comment: It is different. You can lose and find something again.

Comment: @StephenLiu Not really. "Have lost" means it is lost NOW, so it makes no sense to say that, and then in the same sentence say you found it.

Comment: "I had lost my key, but luckily I found it again" - To me, without a context (i.e. the habit of losing keys), "again" seems to be redundant.

Comment: I have seen this sentence by a native English speaker on a forum: "I've bought a car and sold it since last year. " Other native speakers also accept this sentence.

Comment: @StephenLiu Well, there are some problems with that sentence, but yes, you could say "I bought and sold a car" because both those events were part of a sequence and you carried out both in the past. Losing something is different - you cannot say exactly when you lost something because it was an accident! "I have lost my keys" therefore can only mean that your keys are presently lost.

Comment: It does not matter when I lost it. The present perfect doesn't care about the exact time. "I've seen this movie", for example, does not tell us when you saw this movie. And we don't care when.

Comment: @StephenLiu Right well thanks for correcting me Stephen, I can't believe I've been speaking English incorrectly in England for 45 years, and those years at college studying English literature were all a waste of time.

Comment: Well, you can speak perfect English, but you may not know how to explain a grammar. I can't see why "I've bought a car and sold it" works, but "I've lost my key and found it" does not.

Comment: @StephenLiu Some things are just idiomatic and have a specific meaning to native speakers. In this case, "I lost" or "I **had** lost" refers to a past event of losing something, but "I **have** lost" means it is still lost. You're right that tense does not require you know or mention a specific time that something occurred, but thinking logically if you find something then it wasn't actually lost - just misplaced, so in this kind of context it doesn't make sense to say you *have* lost something when it is no longer lost (and arguably never was).

Comment: OK. I see. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. How about if I say "I've misplaced my key and found it this morning" when I'm in the middle of this morning?

Comment: @StephenLiu No, that makes no sense either. "I have misplaced" idiomatically means you *have* put something in the wrong place. If you have found it, it is no longer in the wrong place. You would say "I misplaced my key *but* found it this morning". This follows exactly the same reasoning I have already used in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109136/discussion-between-stephen-liu-and-astralbee).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the present perfect has multiple uses, which are used in different contexts, for example:

I have lost my key = I don't have my key now ( you lost your key at some unspecified time and now you don't have a key)

but it can also be used to express experience: I have lost my key many times but I have always found it again or I have lost my key in the past, but that hasn't happened for a while.

I am afraid you have to accept that only native speakers know when certain expressions are used, that is just the way it is. After all, they are surrounded by that specific language all the time. We, as learners, are not.